# Formar String con comilla simple. Error ORA-01756

Tags: c++, oracle

Estoy ejecutando una sentencia `ORACLE`desde `C++` y recibo este error:

> ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated (OCI_ERROR)

Formo el `string`*sentence* de la siguiente manera:

```
sprintf(sentence, "INSERT INTO \"TABLA\".\"AUTORES\" VALUES('%s', '%s')", autor.nombre, autor.apellido);
```

Donde `autor`es un `struct` declarado así:

```
struct Autor{
    char nombre[100];
    char apellido[100];
}
```

Mi problema llega cuando, por ejemplo, el nombre es "*O'Neill*". En esos casos la comilla simple me da el error. Sé que se soluciona poniendo dos comillas simples `''`. Pero es un bucle que me va a leer un conjunto de `struct` *autor* muy grande y me gustaría poderlo solucionar para todos los casos y no recorriendo además cada nombre y cada apellido.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Aparentemente, te va a tocar hacerlo a mano. No parece existir ninguna función que *escape* las comillas simples. Lo único que te puedo sugerir es que aumentes el tamaño de los arrays `nombre` y `apellido`, para por lo menos ahorrarte la gestión de memória.

Comment: Hola, @trauma, el problema es que son muchos y no los introduzco yo. También podría poner `\'`pero lo que te digo, que no lo introduzco yo y la cantidad de autores que lee el bucle no es fija :/

Comment: No conozco la API de Oracle, pero tras varias búsquedas *a fondo*,  no aparece ningún resultado. **Me temo lo peor ...**

Comment: Yo antes de preguntar también he buscado un montón. He leído algo de Bind parameters, pero de eso aún me estoy documentando y no creo que me lo solucione.

Comment: Los *bind parameters* son para ahorrarte crear las cadenas reales a enviar a la base de datos mediante **sprintf**. Consulta la API de Oracle al respecto, por si fueran capaces de *escapar* los parámetros que les pasas. Tal vez te sirvan.

Comment: Eso es lo que he leído y llevo un rato probando. Si lo consigo me auto responderé.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle dice lo [siguiente](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/quotes.php):

> When the apostrophe/single quote is in the middle of the string, you need to enter 2 single quotes for Oracle to display a quote symbol. For example:

Es decir, en estos casos has de poner dos comillas simples seguidas:

> O'Neil -> O''Neil

Lo más sencillo puede ser crear una función que te permita *preparar* las cadenas:

```
std::string Fix(const std::string& cad)
{
  std::string toReturn;
  for( auto c : cad )
  {
    toReturn += c;
    if( c == '\'' )
      toReturn += c;
  }

  return toReturn;
}
```

Con lo que la línea conflictiva quedaría:

```
sprintf(sentence, "INSERT INTO \"TABLA\".\"AUTORES\" VALUES('%s', '%s')", Fix(autor.nombre), Fix(autor.apellido));
```

---

**Las variables del struct son `char*`**

No es problema. Uno de los construtores de `std::string` acepta un parámetro de tipo `const char*`, es por eso que el siguiente código es capaz de compilar:

```
std::string test = "una prueba";
```

Por otro lado, `std::string` permite obtener su puntero interno, de tipo `char*` de la siguiente forma:

```
const char* ptr = test.c_str();
```

Con esto la llamada correcta a `sprintf` podría quedar así:

```
sprintf(sentence, "INSERT INTO \"TABLA\".\"AUTORES\" VALUES('%s', '%s')",
                  Fix(autor.nombre).c_str(),
                  Fix(autor.apellido).c_str());
```

Si bien esto debería funcionar no parece que sea la solución más elegante. ¿Qué tal si sustituimos `sprintf` por `std::stringstream`?

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << "INSERT INTO \"TABLA\".\"AUTORES\" VALUES('"
       << Fix(autor.nombre) << "','"
       << Fix(autor.apellido) << "')";
```

`std::stringstream` al ser un objeto propio de C++ (en vez de una función heredada de C como es el caso de `sprintf`) dispone de sobrecargas adecuadas para trabajar directamente con la clase `std::string`. ¿Y por qué usar `std::string` en vez de `char*`, pues por varias razones:

- Gestiona la memoria dinámica de forma transparente para el usuario, lo que implica menos quebraderos de cabeza y código más limpio.
- Dispone de múltiples utilidades (como `length()` para conocer el tamaño o `append()` para añadir contenido al final) que facilitan enormemente su uso.

Por supuesto, si además de esto empezamos a tirar de templates podemos darle una nueva vuelta de rosca al código. Por ejemplo podemos tener una función genérica que decida, en tiempo de compilación, si hay que aplicar alguna transformación a los diferentes parámetros o no:

```
template<class T>
struct func_traits
{
  typedef T type;
};

template<class T>
typename func_traits<T>::type Parse(T value)
{ return value; }

// Esta especialización sirve únicamente como demostración
template<>
int Parse<std::string>(int value)
{
  return value*2;
}

template<>
std::string Parse<std::string>(std::string value)
{
  return Fix(value);
}

template<>
const char* Parse<const char*>(const char* value)
{
  return Fix(value).c_str();
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << Parse(std::string("O'Neil")) << '\n'; // std::string
  std::cout << Parse("O'Neil") << '\n'; // const char*
  std::cout << Parse(12) << '\n'; // int
  std::cout << Parse(1.5) << '\n'; // Función genérica
}
```

Salida:

```
O''Neil
O''Neil
24
1.5
```

Si te preguntas sobre el porqué de la existencia de `struct traits` tienes que saber que, directamente, no es posible declarar una plantilla de función cuyo valor de retorno dependa de la especialización del template. Dicho con un ejemplo, lo siguiente no compila:

```
template<class T>
T func(T val)
{ return val; }
```

Sin embargo, si se permite que el valor de retorno lo deduzca a partir de la especialización de un template.

**otra alternativa**

Otra opción que tienes es dejar de crear sentencias SQL directamente y pasar a usar sentencias almacenadas. Hecha un vistazo [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/relational.htm#LNCPP21928). La idea es dejar que sea la API de Oracle la que prepare los argumentos:

```
oraub8 largeRowCount = 0;
Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement("INSERT INTO TABLA.AUTORES values (:1,:2)");
stmt->setString(1, autor.nombre);
stmt->setString(2, autor.apellido);
stmt->executeUpdate();
largeRowCount = stmt->getUb8RowCount();
```

Comment: Lo de añadir otra comilla lo he puesto yo misma en el enunciado de la pregunta. Estaba buscando otra alternativa a eso :/

Comment: Ese comentario debería entonces formar parte de la pregunta. Esta solucion es la más sencilla. Hasta donde sé puedes usar `chr(XX)` como sustituto de la comilla simple de la cadena... pero el proceso sigue siendo el mismo, sustituir `'` por `'||chr(39)||'` o por `' || '''' || '`, sinceramente creo que poner las dos comillas simples es la mejor solución

Comment: Además, `auto`da errores en C++.

Comment: Gracias por responder de todas formas, que eso es lo principal :)

Comment: El último párrafo de la pregunta precisamente habla de recorrer cada nombre y apellido para poner dos comillas simples. Ya estaba puesto en la pregunta.

Comment: `auto` pertenece al estándar C++11 (que data de 2011), quizás deberías plantearte actualizar el compilador (o activar las opciones del nuevo estándar si tu compilador es moderno). De hecho el último estándar en vigor es C++14

Comment: Tampoco funcionaría porque `'%s'`es de tipo `char*`y el argumento que le pasamos por **Fix** es `std::string*`

Comment: Eso no es problema porque `std::string` tiene un constructor a partir de un `char*`. De todas formas ahora edito la pregunta.

Comment: con `Fix(autor.nombre).c_str()`se arregla. Pero ya te digo que yo buscaba algo más general, que eso lo puse en la pregunta ya. Ya que tengo muchas funciones con muchos parámetros del estilo y arreglar todo el código así no me gustaba :/